# is there need of any library to be included with angularjs 1.5 for animation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using angularjs 1.5 version and injected ngAnimate as dependency in my module. I am already using bootstrap in my project for design purposes . My question is that can i use bootstrap for animation or i should integrate some other libraries like green sock etc. If yes than how to include this library and integrate with angularjs 1.5 version.

My second question is that can we customize green sock ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use bootstrap for animation. And yes you can do customise green sock by do changes in their properties.